# how to pause the UI thread in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering what a clean way is to pause the UI thread in javascript?  Just for a couple seconds, I have a really good reason to.

Comment: Is "working for a major electrical power company" considered a good reason?

Answer (score 2):

Spinwait.

```
while(Date.now() < some_target_time) {}
```

Enjoy the infinite streams of hatred from your users and fellow developers.

Comment: :)  I wish the "haters gonna hate" tag hadn't been edited away

Comment: [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) is not supported in IE<9 and performance isn't really an issue here, `while (new Date().getTime() < milliseconds_to_wait)` can be used instead to support IE<=8 without shims.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt mentioned, "spinwait" is pretty much the only solution. Here's a working code sample, change 1000 to the number of milliseconds you want the browser to unpleasantly grind away doing nothing.

```
for (var wait = + new Date() + 1000; + new Date() < wait;);
```